# How to make one row and sum up values in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to make one line per `PolicyNumber`.

First, I need to check if there is more than one `ControlNo` per `PolicyNumber`, 
if yes, than I need   to sum premium per `PolicyNumber`  and leave only the row where  `StatusReason = "Rewrite (Agency Reason)`".

Code example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(
     EffectiveDate DATE, 
     QuoteID INT, 
     ControlNo INT,  
     PolicyNumber VARCHAR(50), 
     PolicyType VARCHAR(50), 
     StatusReason VARCHAR(100), 
     Premium MONEY
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
VALUES ('2019-01-01', 884867, 1111, 'Poliy1', 'New Business', 'Rewrite (Agency Reason)', 0.00),
       ('2019-01-01', 993456,2222, 'Poliy1', 'Rewrite', 'Driver Added', 1965.00),
       ('2019-03-01', 54545,3333, 'Poliy2', 'Rewrite', 'Other Reason', 1123.00),
       ('2019-04-01', 78935,4444, 'Poliy3', 'Renewal', 'Rewrite (Agency Reason)', 0.00),
       ('2019-04-01', 88884,5555, 'Poliy3', 'Rewrite', 'Driver Added', 100.00)

SELECT * FROM #MyTable
```

[image]

The output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: There is only one row for `Policy2`. Why it exists in the expected output? Thanks.

Comment: tell the logic for selecting "New Business" for Poliy1.

Comment: Its just an example,  that row need to stay as is because StatusReason is not "Rewrite (Agency Reason)".

Comment: why does new business have 1,965? It is not listed in the table with any premium value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `ControlNo` is sequential, you can use row_number() to identify the top record.

```
Select EffectiveDate
      ,PolicyNumber
      ,PolicyType = max(case when RN=1 then PolicyType end)
      ,Premium    = sum(Premium)
 From  (Select *
               ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By EffectiveDate,PolicyNumber Order By ControlNo)
         From  #MyTable
       ) A
 Group By 
       EffectiveDate
      ,PolicyNumber
```

Returns

```
EffectiveDate   PolicyNumber    PolicyType      Premium
2019-01-01      Poliy1          New Business    1965.00
2019-03-01      Poliy2          Rewrite         1123.00
2019-04-01      Poliy3          Renewal         100.00
```

Comment: @SeanLange Triple dose of caffeine.